# Krita PNG or JPEG not saving?

Tags: export, png, jpg, krita

I've tried a grand total of 12 times to save my Krita files (called .kra) as .png or .jpg files, but it doesn't work. Each time I try, Krita freezes for a few minutes and then shuts down without saving it as either of the files.

Is this just my computer, or does this have to do with the program?

Could I open it in a different program and save from there, or is that impossible?

Comment: Have you tried flattining all layers first?

Comment: Really late, but still leaving a comment: flattening layers won't matter. It's automatically done in the saved result, without actually doing it in Krita. If you re-load the PNG though, the layers will of course be gone, because they aren't stored. The PNG contains the raw image, but the layers themselves still exist until Krita is closed, or they're removed/merged. Could be that it fails to merge them depending on the underlaying hardware, but I can save PNG's without manually merging them (and still seeing layers afterwards, but obviously not if I load from the PNG)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `Save As` command, try `File > Export` and select the desired file type. It proves to be more effective when saving as JPG or PNG.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows, so when you are saving the document it got a name (for example):
krita.kra

just flatten the layers, then switch its name to:
krita.PNG

or
krita.jpg

and so to any program you want to convert it to.
(not include internetic site like pdf).